# How to high light rows in list control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, componentone

I'm using C1List control named `lstPats` in my vb.net form.`lstPats` have id,patname,patemail columns, i need to colour the rows in `lstPats` if `patemail` value  is null

what I have done so far is

> enabled fetchrowstyle property of lstPats
>
> following is the code that i've written in `lstPats_FetchRowStyle` event

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To lstPats.ListCount - 1
         If lstPats.GetItemText(i, 2) <> "" Then /* checks the patemail is null or not*/
            e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green
         End If
     Next
```

The problem is all rows in the `lstPats` turns green, I need only the row(s) that contains null value in column `patemail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite the code in `FetchRowsStyle` *Event* like below to highlight only some rows

```
 Dim val As String = Me.lstPats.Columns(2).CellText(e.Row).ToString
 If val <> "" Then
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
 End If
```